# jQuery function has to repeat to work

Tags: jquery

I'm just getting into jQuery and notice strange behavior in the way some of my code is executed. When I execute a function based on a click action, the function runs twice, the first time with an "undefined" value for the click and the second with the expected value. The end result is the code "works" but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong that is causing this unexpected behavior.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

//$('#venue').buttonset().click(function(event, ui) {
//$( '#venue' ).buttonset().live('click', function (event, ui) { 
  $('#venue').buttonset().unbind('click').bind('click', function(event, ui) {

    var venueName = $("input[name='venue']:checked").val();

    if (venueName == "venue2") {
        alert("About to deselect, venue: " + venueName);
        $("#meallist option[value='Dinner']").removeAttr("selected");
    } else {
        alert("Doing nothing, venue: " + venueName);
    }
  });
});
```

Note the three different ways of expressing the click action at the top, derived from jQuery docs and previous answers on this site. All have the same outcome. You can try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qaxx3/6/

Thanks for any insight. I'm hoping it's a simple newbie mistake.

Comment: Problem because of buttonset() , if you remove that it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set the click event on the element containing the inputs.
if you set it directly on the inputs it works as expected:

```
$('#venue').buttonset().find('input').click(function(event, ui) {
```

Comment: This answer is simplest and is the only one that doesn't repeat itself, provides the expected value, and maintains the jQuery UI elements I wanted. This may be more of an issue with how I asked the question than with how others answered - thanks all for your suggestions.

Comment: @k3davis glad i could help. For me your question was pretty clear

Answer (score 0):

Neither one of your radios is checked by default. Works if I change the source in the fiddle to:

```
<input type="radio" value="venue1" name="venue" id="venue1" checked="checked">
```

If you don't want either selected by default, use the `change` event and `preventDefault`: Code below works in your fiddle:

```
$(function () {
    //$('#venue').buttonset().click(function(event, ui) {
    //$( '#venue' ).buttonset().live('click', function (event, ui) { 
    $('#venue').buttonset().bind('change', function (event, ui) {
        var venueName = $("input[name='venue']:checked").val();
        if (venueName == "venue2") {
            alert("About to deselect, venue: " + venueName);
            $("#meallist option[value='Dinner']").removeAttr("selected");
        } else {
            alert("Doing nothing, venue: " + venueName);
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: I definitely don't want to have either radio checked by default, but that's an interesting observation.

Comment: Took another look as you don't want either checked by default. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `event.stopPropagation()` somewhere in your function to stop event bubbling. Like so:

```
  $('#venue').buttonset().unbind('click').bind('click', function(event, ui) {
      // ... your code
      event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

or you can just return false:

```
  $('#venue').buttonset().unbind('click').bind('click', function(event, ui) {
      // ... your code
      return false;
  }
```

Otherwise the event is "passed through" to the parent div, which will also trigger the same click event, and execute your code another time

--- btw, 'undefined' is the value your radio button will have when none of them is selected (which is your default state now...). And is there a reason you unbind the 'click' event at first?

Comment: Adding `event.stopPropagation();` seemed to have no effect, and while returning false preventing the second loop, it also breaks it since it stops on the first loop which unexpectedly returns a value of "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

try using class = "venue" instead of name, since it is duplicated it might call the handler 2 times.
`$('.venue').buttonset().unbind('click').bind('click', function(event, ui) {` is called only once!

edit: check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Qaxx3/33/

Comment: This is a good answer (thanks for the fiddle update, as I wasn't initially sure what you meant). It drops the buttonset, but I didn't state that desire specifically in my question.